# How do shader compilers work?

Tags: compiler-construction, shader

Does anyone have references to documents and research specific on the inner workings of shader compilers/graphics drivers compilers?

Answer (score 0):

There's no big difference between writing an ordinary C compiler and writing a shader compiler. The standard book on writing compilers is the so called "Dragon Book":

[http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpi_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811)

Comment: I know about the dragon book and compilers in general. I'm seeking information specific to shader compilers, i.e. vectorization and so on. I remember seeing a research paper once but can't find it now