# How is a shader run time implemented?

Tags: compiler-construction, shader, llvm, compiler-optimization

I just finished the LLVM tutorial(kaleidoscope). And now I am planning my first project based on LLVM for practice.

My goal is to write a shader compiler/run time which is similar to GLSL or HLSL. But I find it very difficult to start.

There are many papers/techniques/tools on the web, such as https://ispc.github.io/ and http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html. But I do not know whether these things fit my goal.

I searched around on the stackoverflow and found this: [How do shader compilers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558974/how-do-shader-compilers-work)
The answer in that post is too general for me.

To make my question more specific, I focus on the backend(the run time) of a shader.
Especially following sub-questions:

- Suppose I have had an AST already. How can I generate code so that I can apply the JIT-ted instructions on multiple data?

  I guess a sophisticated shader run time would not be such naive like this:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < dataSetSize; ++i) {
      ApplyJITtedFunction(shaderProgram, element[i]);
  }
  ```
- How to handle branch(`if`s, `while`s)?
- How to organize memory layout of data set so that data parallelism is maximum exploited?
- How to order the computation on every element of data set
  so that the data access is local(I think it is important for some old CUDA device, whose memory access pattern(e.g. coalescing) is very different from CPU.)?